# What should I use for common parts of UI in Android application?

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is Uber Android application. As you see each of screen has some common elements: header, map control etc. But each view has different header buttons and subview with some view specific details.

Should this screens be separate activities?
Is fragments API right thing to implement this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I prefer to use fragments here

Comment: Why did you make an iOS User interface and forgot about all android standards? (cancel button when you have a back physical button, resources for refresh button) you should read this one: http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/04/5-tips-for-converting-ios-ui-to-android.html